# latex template for Journal of Business and Economic Statistics

Tags: templates

Could anyone let me know if such a template is available? I have been searching for a while with no luck...

Thanks a lot in advance!
David

Comment: I don't know what their requirement is, but if it is two column, you could use `\documentclass[journal]{IEEEtran}`

Comment: Please register on this site, too like SE otherwise you won't be able to comment on or accept answers or edit your question

Answer (score 5):

Like most journals, google for the journal name leads to a page with author submission guidelines. In this case

http://www.tandfonline.com/action/authorSubmission?journalCode=ubes20&page=instructions#.Ucy1r-IkBBk

which says:

> Authors are encouraged to use LaTeX if possible, and should use
>   “article” style, avoiding the use of any special macros

So

```
\documentclass{article}
```

is all you need.

Comment: I'm not sure that OP was looking for a template to submit to JBES. They were probably looking for a template to make their article match the style of the journal.